# catch switching activity event when using back button

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two Activities in my app. lets call them **First** and **Second**.

`FirstActivity` is the launching activity. I am switching from `FirstActivity`  to `SecondActivity` using the `startActivity()` method. now if I back to the `FirstActivity` from `SecondActivity` by pressing the back button how can I catch the event inside the `FirstActivity` .

**for example,** if I would use `startActivityForResult` method to start the second activity, I could catch the event using the `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: use `onResume` method in first activity

Comment: well this event do work but the onResume method is also called when the first activity launches for the first time.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences or have a static variable to identify

Comment: I have updated my code, Please check @GolamRahmanTushar

Comment: In what situations do you need this information?

Comment: @DavidWasser I have a editTextView in the first activity. I am passing the text of that editTextView to the second activity. Now, when I get back to the first activity from second activity using the back button, I want the editTextView field cleared. Yes I know I can clear the text when I am switching activity or using onResume method or using the startActivityForResult method. But none of these options seemed logical to me.

Comment: Clear the `EditText` when you start the secxond `Activity`. This is the clearest and cleanest approach. Anything else is a hack.

Answer (score 0):

By startActivityForResult : It will give data what you will get from your next Activity by startActivityForResult by getting data from your next activity you can easily find the Activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);

     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
            if(result.equals("SECOND_ACTIVITY"){
             //Action here
            }else if(result.equals("THIRD_ACTIVITY"){
             //Action here
            }else{

              }

        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

from your Second Activity :

```
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result","SECOND_ACTIVITY");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

from your Third Activity :

```
  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result","THIRD_ACTIVITY");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: well I mentioned in the question that I know I can do this if I use startActivityForResult method while switching activity. But I want to use the startActivity method as I am switching to second activity not for any result. So it make more sense if I use startActivity method.

Comment: by onBackPress(); method you can do this thing.